# What is $Hom_{A}(A[x],A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

So given a ring $A$ and $A[x]$ the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $A$

If we see $A[x]$ as a module over A, then how can I compute $Hom_{A}(A[x],A)$?

Is it possible to give an explicit description of $Hom_{A}(A[x],A)$?

Im just new to studying modules so I found hard to compute something explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an $A$-module, $A[x]$ is just a direct sum of countably many copies of $A$, so this is the direct product of countably many copies of $A$ (assuming $A$ is commutative so it's unambiguous what $A[x]$ means).

Comment: I get that $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A=A[x]$ but how do you conclude that then it should be the direct product of countably many copies of $A$?

Comment: Note that Hom$(A, A) \cong A$, and Hom$(\oplus A,A) \cong \prod$ Hom$(A,A)$, and now use the firet isomorphism.